# Server run web.xml vs local run web.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-3, web.xml

I am into a new project now. While analyzing the source code, I found this Java EE web application has some different files in web-inf. It has 3 web.xml like web(server-run).xml, web(local-run).xml and web.xml. They almost have similar elements. I am confused on what these files are. Anyone knows? Are these manually created files or automatically generated files something based on maven profiles. Please clarify

Comment: Whatever it is, it's non-standard. The container is interested in *web.xml*, and related fragments

Answer (score 0):

those are not exactly web.xml files you can have more than one xml files in web-info but not web.xml. all those xml's file must be configured in some root xml file any how container will read only the standard web.xml file only.
can you provide those xml files.. so that i can explain which xml is for what purpose.